# Symfony 4: Using Factories of a Service to instantiate multiple objects

Tags: symfony4

I have a class Path that represents a regular path and can do some magic stuff with it. Anytime I want to deal with paths in my app, I want to quickly instantiate a Path object and continue working with it. The Path class has some dependencies and I want to use autowiring / dependency injection.

**What I have tried:**

I have the class in place as a service and created a factory method, similar to what is described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html. The factory method receives the dependencies as arguments and stores them in private attributes.
I was able to get new instances by simply using a dependency injection wherever I need an instance. No problems with the dependencies here.
Now the problem is that I can only get one instance using dependency injections. Yes, I could clone a "plain" object over an over, but I guess there is a better solution.
Calling the factory method by hand doesn't work because of the dependency injection in there.

The service and controller:

```php
<?
// Service
namespace App\Service;

class Path {
    private $dep;

    public function __construct(DependencyName $dep) {
        $this->dep = $dep;
    }

    public static function factory(DependencyName $dep) {
        $path = new Path($dep);
        return $path;
    }

    // some methods
}

// Controller
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\Path;

class SomeController {
    public function generatePaths() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            $paths[] = Path::factory(/* missing dependencies */);
        }
    }

    public function __construct(Path $path) {
        // here I can have one Path without a problem
        // but I need more than one
    }
}
```

in services.yaml:

```
App\Service\Path:
        # call the static method
        factory: ['App\Service\Path', 'factory']
```

**More general**: how can I **create multiple instances of a service** that has **dependencies**, when I use autowiring?
The solution should not be limited to controllers. I need to use this service in other services as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`shared`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html) option in your service definition:

> In the service container, all services are shared by default. This
>   means that [...] you'll get the same instance. In some cases, you
>   might want to always get a new instance.

By doing this (as I understand your `Dependency` is always the same) you wouldn't need the `factory` method anymore and could change the definition to:

```
App\Service\Path:
        class: App\Service\Path
        shared: false
```

To have more than one instance you can't use injection, so you'll need to implement [`ServiceSubscriberInterface`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#defining-a-service-subscriber) and register your service so you can retrieve it manually from the container each time you need it while still taking advantage of autowiring.

I won't go into much detail, since there are several options and one might make more sense than others, but once implemented, doing:

```
$path = $this->get('path_builder'); // Whatever your alias is
```

Will get you a new instance every time.